# Confusing behaviour when invoking async methods inside ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I created an ASP WebApplication using Visual Studio 2012.

If I modify the default page as follows:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    static async Task PerformSleepingTask()
    {
        Action action = () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
            int dummy = 3; // Just a nice place to put a break point
        };
        await Task.Run(action);
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task performSleepingTask = PerformSleepingTask();
        performSleepingTask.Wait();
    }
}
```

On the call to `performSleepingTask.Wait()` it hangs indefinitely.

---

Interestingly, if I set this in the web.config:

```
<appSettings>

    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Then it does work. The `Wait` function waits for the sleeping to finish on a different thread, then continues.

---

Can somebody explain:

- Why does it hang?
- Why do they have something called `TaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`? (Given that it causes tasks to hang, I wouldn't call it "friendly")

---

- Is there a "best practice" for invoking `async` methods from page handler methods?

Here's an implementation I came up with which works, but it feels like clumsy code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Action act = () =>
        {
            Task performSleepingTask = PerformSleepingTask();
            performSleepingTask.Wait();
            mre.Set();
        };
        act.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        mre.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you would want to make a thread sleep on an aspx page

Comment: @Lawrence Johnson - This is a deliberately contrived example, written for the purpose of illustrating the behavior. You can imagine it as "PerformExpensiveDatabaseTasks" if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does it hang?

The `Task` representing `PerformSleepingTask` is trying to resume after its `await` so that `PerformSleepingTask` can return. It is trying to re-enter the ASP.NET request context, which is blocked by the call to `Wait`. [This causes a deadlock, as I expound on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

To avoid the deadlock, follow these best practices:

1. Use `async` all the way down. Don't block on `async` code.
2. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your "library" methods.

> Why do they have something called `TaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`? (Given that it causes tasks to hang, I wouldn't call it "friendly")

`TaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` uses the new `AspNetSynchronizationContext` (the .NET 4.0 `TaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` has been renamed `LegacyTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`), and it also uses a new, `async`-aware pipeline.

I'm not 100% sure about this one, but I *suspect* that the reason `Page_Load` works for the legacy SyncCtx is that the old pipeline wasn't putting the SyncCtx in place yet. I'm not sure why it would act this way, though (unless `Page.Async` was `false`).

> Is there a "best practice" for invoking async methods from page handler methods?

[Absolutely](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45). You can either just make your event handlers `async void`, or use `RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(...));`. The first approach is easier but the second approach is favored by the ASP.NET team.

Comment: Again, if you have *any* involvement with a project you are recommending or a link you are pushing (say, to your blog), then you *must* provide disclosure.  I see [183 posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A263693+url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fnitoprograms.blogspot.com%2F*%22) that should have this disclosure, and this one certainly doesn't.  Failure to do so may result in further moderator action.  Also, almost 20% of your posts reference your blog.  Note the part of the FAQ that states "if a good number of your posts are for promotion, this may not be the site for you".

Comment: Since I'm limited to 5 edits per day, this may take a while to clean up. Please be patient.

Comment: Of course, but please keep this in mind when constructing *new* answers.